# How do I prevent screen wakeup while using a remote access tool?

Tags: 18.04, wakeup, xset

I'm trying to design a system for our office (consisting of Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS laptops and desktops), where remote access to the on-screen GUI can be combined with a local screen-blank, for privacy from co-workers.

Of all the tools I've trialed so far, the best ones seem not to support the screen blanking functionality, so I've been trying to devise my own method.

The result of `xset dpms force standby` is absolutely perfect, however I don't seem to be able to temporarily disable any wakeup functionality (the physical monitors reactivate as soon as any remote session input is detected).

I've tried echoing device codes to `/proc/acpi/wakeup` but that doesn't seem to be what's causing the screens to power back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, the best solution is to run `xrandr --output ${display_name} --brightness 0`.
It will blank corresponding display.
Do it for all connected displays.

To get display back, use `--brightness 1`.